# Loading native library with WildFly 10

Tags: java, linux, jboss, wildfly, jna

So I have a web service that contains code that uses native library code. I have a module set up based on this article https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Native+Libraries:

```
com
   myco
      mymodule
         main
            myjar.jar
            myjar2.jar
            myjar3.jar
            module.xml
            lib
               linux-x86_64
                  libTimeFunc.so
```

Here is my `module.xml` file:

```
<module name="com.myco.mymodule" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="myjar.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="myjar2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="myjar3.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

`myjar.jar` depeonds on `myjar2.jar` which depends on `myjar3.jar`. `myjar3.jar` makes some native library calls using `libTimeFunc.so`. That article said to have `lib/linux-x86_64` for 64-bit Linux, which is what I'm running on.

When the service tries to make the call, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TimeFunc': Native library (linux-x86-64/libTimeFunc.so) not found in resource path (/jboss/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/jboss-modules.jar)`.

I noticed that it seemed to be looking for `linux-x86-64/libTimeFunc.so`, instead of `linux-x86_64/libTimeFunc.so`, but when I tried changing the folder name to have a dash, I still got the same error.

My `pom.xml` file for my service has the following to depend on the module (there are other entries within the plugin, this was just the relevant portion):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries> 
                <Dependencies>
                    com.myco.mymodule
                </Dependencies>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Why would it not be able to find the `libTimeFunc.so` file? From what I understand I should just be able to put it under `lib/linux-x86_64` and it should automatically look there for it.

Comment: JNA uses `ClassLoader.getResource("linux-x86-64/libTimeFunc.so")` to find your native library as a last resort.  Unless your class loader uses `/com/myco/mymodule/main/lib` as its default resource prefix, it's not going to find your native library where it is currently located.  You can either reconfigure the class loader to use that prefix, or [move the file to where JNA will find it](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html).

Comment: Hm, okay. I'll try setting the `jna.library.path` in our `standalone.conf` file.

Comment: `jna.library.path` applies only to on-disk paths.  If you want JNA to unpack the shared library for you, you'll need to move it within your resource path.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by on-disk path? Why doesn't starting up JBoss with `-Djna.library.path=/path/to/libs` allow it to find those libraries (assuming `/path/to/libs` is a folder in my filesystem that contains the `.so` file)?

Comment: And the article I posted made it seem like you could just put the native libraries in that special `lib/<osname>-<cpuname>` folder and it would automatically look there when trying to load a native library: "The module class loader will search for native libraries by encoding the current detected platform into a directory name, appending it to the path of the "lib" directory, and testing the resultant directory for a matching native library file."

Comment: The article was likely referring to libraries directly linked with JNI and loaded via `System.load()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is running in the context of an application server, you should load your shared library using the class loader used to load your application.  That way the native library gets unloaded when your application does.

```
Map options = new HashMap();
options.put(Library.OPTION_CLASSLOADER, loader);
Native.loadLibrary("libTimeFunc", options);
```

You then need to move the `linux-x86-64` directory to the root of your archive so the class loader can find it there.

Alternatively, you can specify an absolute path to your library, e.g.

```
Native.loadLibrary("/com/myco/mymodule/main/lib/linux-x86-64/libTimeFunc.so", options);
```

Note that your application server may not be particularly happy with your app copying a resource to disk and then attempting to load it.  Your `SecurityManager` mileage may vary.

You may also encounter a version of JNA already loaded by your application server.